# Create Textview with neon effect

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio, material3

I need to create textview just like this site text:
https://customneon.com/create-neon-sign

any suggestion?
i write this, but didnt looks good

```
<TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="15dp"
                android:shadowColor="@color/neon_red"
                android:shadowDx="0"
                android:shadowDy="0"
                android:shadowRadius="50"
                android:text="@string/app_name"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="40sp" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I try to follow you, show that the following

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ljS9T.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).